# "NoneType" object has no attribute 'blit buffer'

Tags: python, android, kivy

I am trying to make an Android application with kivy, buildozer and opencv, so I am following a model that I find that comes from here:

[kivy camera application with opencv in android shows black screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61122285/kivy-camera-application-with-opencv-in-android-shows-black-screen/67061962#67061962)

The code I am using is the following:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
from kivy.lang import Builder
import numpy as np
import cv2
from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission

request_permissions([
   Permission.Camera])



Builder.load_file("myapplayout.kv")

class AndroidCamera(Camera):
    camera_resolution = (640, 480)
    counter = 0


    def _camera_loaded(self, *largs):
        self.texture = Texture.create(size=np.flip(self.camera_resolution), colorfmt='rgb')
        self.texture_size = list(self.texture.size)

    def on_tex(self, *l):
        if self._camera._buffer is None:
            return None
        frame = self.frame_from_buf()

        self.frame_to_screen(frame)
        super(AndroidCamera, self).on_tex(*l)

    def frame_from_buf(self):
        w, h = self.resolution
        frame = np.frombuffer(self._camera._buffer.tostring(), 'uint8').reshape((h + h // 2, w))
        frame_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(frame, 93)
        return np.rot90(frame_bgr, 3)

    def frame_to_screen(self, frame):
        frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        cv2.putText(frame_rgb, str(self.counter), (20, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
        self.counter += 1
        flipped = np.flip(frame_rgb, 0)
        buf = flipped.tostring()
        self.texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='rgb', bufferfmt='ubyte')

class MyLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

The application is compiled correctly, when entering the app it asks me for the permissions to use the camera but it closes automatically, it uses abd logcat and the error that is generated is because of this:

```
--------- beginning of main
07-27 11:27:54.077 18226 18282 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 24)
07-27 11:27:54.077 18226 18282 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
07-27 11:27:54.079 18226 18282 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_22-07-27_0.txt
07-27 11:27:54.080 18226 18282 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0
07-27 11:27:54.080 18226 18282 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/__init__.pyc"
07-27 11:27:54.080 18226 18282 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.9 (main, Jul 27 2022, 10:35:24)
07-27 11:27:54.080 18226 18282 I python  : [Clang 12.0.8 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project c935d99d
07-27 11:27:54.080 18226 18282 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at ""
07-27 11:27:54.080 18226 18282 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
07-27 11:27:54.081 18226 18282 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
07-27 11:27:54.611 18226 18282 I python  : [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 189 symbols loaded
07-27 11:27:54.765 18226 18282 I python  : [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
07-27 11:27:54.840 18226 18282 I python  : [INFO   ] [Camera      ] Provider: android
07-27 11:27:55.020 18226 18282 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
07-27 11:27:55.042 18226 18282 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
07-27 11:27:55.043 18226 18282 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
07-27 11:27:55.043 18226 18282 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 3.2 v1.r32p1-00bet5.527d5f870bb3ff272c163c104e655d0f'>
07-27 11:27:55.043 18226 18282 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'ARM'>
07-27 11:27:55.043 18226 18282 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Mali-G57 MC3'>
07-27 11:27:55.044 18226 18282 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 2
07-27 11:27:55.044 18226 18282 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16383>
07-27 11:27:55.044 18226 18282 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <128>
07-27 11:27:55.080 18226 18282 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
07-27 11:27:55.081 18226 18282 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
07-27 11:27:55.092 18226 18282 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
07-27 11:27:55.093 18226 18282 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 60, in <module>
07-27 11:27:55.094 18226 18282 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/app.py", line 954, in run
07-27 11:27:55.094 18226 18282 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/app.py", line 924, in _run_prepare
07-27 11:27:55.095 18226 18282 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 56, in build
07-27 11:27:55.095 18226 18282 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/uix/boxlayout.py", line 145, in __init__
07-27 11:27:55.095 18226 18282 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/uix/layout.py", line 76, in __init__
07-27 11:27:55.095 18226 18282 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 366, in __init__
07-27 11:27:55.095 18226 18282 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 470, in apply_class_lang_rules
07-27 11:27:55.096 18226 18282 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 540, in apply
07-27 11:27:55.096 18226 18282 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 658, in _apply_rule
07-27 11:27:55.096 18226 18282 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/uix/camera.py", line 91, in __init__
07-27 11:27:55.096 18226 18282 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/uix/camera.py", line 103, in _on_index
07-27 11:27:55.096 18226 18282 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/core/camera/camera_android.py", line 42, in __init__
07-27 11:27:55.096 18226 18282 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/core/camera/__init__.py", line 70, in __init__
07-27 11:27:55.097 18226 18282 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/core/camera/camera_android.py", line 49, in init_camera
07-27 11:27:55.097 18226 18282 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 1177, in jnius.jnius.JavaMultipleMethod.__call__
07-27 11:27:55.097 18226 18282 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 884, in jnius.jnius.JavaMethod.__call__
07-27 11:27:55.097 18226 18282 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 1056, in jnius.jnius.JavaMethod.call_staticmethod
07-27 11:27:55.097 18226 18282 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_utils.pxi", line 91, in jnius.jnius.check_exception
07-27 11:27:55.097 18226 18282 I python  :  jnius.jnius.JavaException: JVM exception occurred: Fail to connect to camera service java.lang.RuntimeException
07-27 11:27:55.097 18226 18282 I python  : Python for android ended.
07-27 11:27:59.066 18331 18382 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_22-07-27_1.txt
07-27 11:27:59.067 18331 18382 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0
07-27 11:27:59.067 18331 18382 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/__init__.pyc"
07-27 11:27:59.067 18331 18382 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.9 (main, Jul 27 2022, 10:35:24)
07-27 11:27:59.067 18331 18382 I python  : [Clang 12.0.8 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project c935d99d
07-27 11:27:59.067 18331 18382 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at ""
07-27 11:27:59.068 18331 18382 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
07-27 11:27:59.068 18331 18382 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
07-27 11:27:59.644 18331 18382 I python  : [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 189 symbols loaded
07-27 11:27:59.801 18331 18382 I python  : [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
07-27 11:27:59.877 18331 18382 I python  : [INFO   ] [Camera      ] Provider: android
07-27 11:28:00.061 18331 18382 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
07-27 11:28:00.109 18331 18382 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
07-27 11:28:00.112 18331 18382 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
07-27 11:28:00.112 18331 18382 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 3.2 v1.r32p1-00bet5.527d5f870bb3ff272c163c104e655d0f'>
07-27 11:28:00.112 18331 18382 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'ARM'>
07-27 11:28:00.113 18331 18382 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Mali-G57 MC3'>
07-27 11:28:00.113 18331 18382 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 2
07-27 11:28:00.113 18331 18382 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16383>
07-27 11:28:00.113 18331 18382 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <128>
07-27 11:28:00.139 18331 18382 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
07-27 11:28:00.140 18331 18382 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
07-27 11:28:00.379 18331 18382 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
07-27 11:28:00.781 18331 18382 I python  : [WARNING] [Base        ] Unknown <android> provider
07-27 11:28:00.782 18331 18382 I python  : [INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
07-27 11:28:01.622 18331 18382 I python  :  /home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/app/main.py:47: DeprecationWarning: tostring() is deprecated. Use tobytes() instead.
07-27 11:28:01.633 18331 18382 I python  : [INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
07-27 11:28:01.633 18331 18382 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
07-27 11:28:01.633 18331 18382 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 60, in <module>
07-27 11:28:01.636 18331 18382 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/app.py", line 955, in run
07-27 11:28:01.636 18331 18382 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/base.py", line 574, in runTouchApp
07-27 11:28:01.637 18331 18382 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/base.py", line 339, in mainloop
07-27 11:28:01.637 18331 18382 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/base.py", line 379, in idle
07-27 11:28:01.637 18331 18382 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/clock.py", line 733, in tick
07-27 11:28:01.638 18331 18382 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/clock.py", line 776, in post_idle
07-27 11:28:01.638 18331 18382 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 620, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
07-27 11:28:01.638 18331 18382 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 653, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
07-27 11:28:01.638 18331 18382 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 649, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
07-27 11:28:01.639 18331 18382 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 218, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
07-27 11:28:01.639 18331 18382 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/core/camera/camera_android.py", line 159, in _update
07-27 11:28:01.639 18331 18382 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/core/camera/camera_android.py", line 166, in _copy_to_gpu
07-27 11:28:01.640 18331 18382 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 727, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
07-27 11:28:01.640 18331 18382 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1307, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
07-27 11:28:01.641 18331 18382 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1231, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
07-27 11:28:01.641 18331 18382 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 33, in on_tex
07-27 11:28:01.641 18331 18382 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 48, in frame_to_screen
07-27 11:28:01.642 18331 18382 I python  :  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'blit_buffer'
07-27 11:28:01.642 18331 18382 I python  : Python for android ended.
07-27 12:04:42.036 11448 11501 I python  : [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 189 symbols loaded
07-27 12:04:42.210 11448 11501 I python  : [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
07-27 12:04:42.298 11448 11501 I python  : [INFO   ] [Camera      ] Provider: android
07-27 12:04:42.676 11448 11501 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
07-27 12:04:42.709 11448 11501 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
07-27 12:04:42.710 11448 11501 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
07-27 12:04:42.710 11448 11501 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 3.2 v1.r32p1-00bet5.527d5f870bb3ff272c163c104e655d0f'>
07-27 12:04:42.710 11448 11501 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'ARM'>
07-27 12:04:42.710 11448 11501 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Mali-G57 MC3'>
07-27 12:04:42.711 11448 11501 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 2
07-27 12:04:42.711 11448 11501 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16383>
07-27 12:04:42.711 11448 11501 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <128>
07-27 12:04:42.739 11448 11501 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
07-27 12:04:42.741 11448 11501 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
07-27 12:04:42.925 11448 11501 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
07-27 12:04:43.263 11448 11501 I python  : [WARNING] [Base        ] Unknown <android> provider
07-27 12:04:43.264 11448 11501 I python  : [INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
07-27 12:04:43.832 11448 11501 I python  :  /home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/app/main.py:47: DeprecationWarning: tostring() is deprecated. Use tobytes() instead.
07-27 12:04:43.849 11448 11501 I python  : [INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
07-27 12:04:43.849 11448 11501 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
07-27 12:04:43.849 11448 11501 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 60, in <module>
07-27 12:04:43.851 11448 11501 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/app.py", line 955, in run
07-27 12:04:43.852 11448 11501 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/base.py", line 574, in runTouchApp
07-27 12:04:43.852 11448 11501 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/base.py", line 339, in mainloop
07-27 12:04:43.853 11448 11501 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/base.py", line 379, in idle
07-27 12:04:43.853 11448 11501 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/clock.py", line 733, in tick
07-27 12:04:43.854 11448 11501 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/clock.py", line 776, in post_idle
07-27 12:04:43.854 11448 11501 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 620, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
07-27 12:04:43.854 11448 11501 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 653, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
07-27 12:04:43.855 11448 11501 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 649, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
07-27 12:04:43.855 11448 11501 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 218, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
07-27 12:04:43.856 11448 11501 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/core/camera/camera_android.py", line 159, in _update
07-27 12:04:43.857 11448 11501 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/core/camera/camera_android.py", line 166, in _copy_to_gpu
07-27 12:04:43.857 11448 11501 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 727, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
07-27 12:04:43.858 11448 11501 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1307, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
07-27 12:04:43.858 11448 11501 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1231, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
07-27 12:04:43.859 11448 11501 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 33, in on_tex
07-27 12:04:43.859 11448 11501 I python  :    File "/home/hcardenas/PycharmProjects/Kivy_camera/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 48, in frame_to_screen
07-27 12:04:43.860 11448 11501 I python  :  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'blit_buffer'
07-27 12:04:43.860 11448 11501 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

I do not understand what could be the error, what is it that I would be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. If you remove the line  `self.texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='rgb', bufferfmt='ubyte')` it will show the camera. but not what opencv is creating since the texture never gets updated. Based on what I have researched so far, the problem is that in the latest Kivy version they removed the `_camera_loaded` function from the camera. So overwriting that function  does nothing. I guess the solution is to overwrite the texture of camera which I am not sure how.

Ok i figured it out. You can delete the  _camera_loaded function since it no longer does anything with kivy's current version. Move the

- self.texture = Texture.create(size=np.flip(self.camera_resolution),
  colorfmt='rgb')
  -self.texture_size = list(self.texture.size)

to the on_tex code and PUT IT AFTER the super(AndroidCamera,self).on_tex(*l) line.

If you don't the original on_tex command of the Kivy Camera Class runs and overwrites the new texture with the core.camera class' texture.