# Generating the rectangle around the face isn't working - OpenCV, Kivy

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, kivy

I was able to detect faces in a live camera feed using OpenCV, however I couldn't generate the rectangle around their faces.

Here's my current code as of the moment:

```
def get_frame(self, dt):
        cam = self.root.ids.a_cam
        image_object = cam.export_as_image(scale=round((400 / int(cam.height)), 2))
        w, h = image_object._texture.size
        frame = np.frombuffer(image_object._texture.pixels, 'uint8').reshape(h, w, 4)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY)
        faces = self.faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray,
                                                scaleFactor=1.1,
                                                minNeighbors=5,
                                                minSize=(60, 60),
                                                flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)
        if len(faces) != 0:
            print("{} Face detected".format(len(faces)))
            for (x,y,width,height) in faces:
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + width, y + height),(0,255,0), 2)
                faceROI = gray[y:y+height,x:x+width]
        else:
            print('Face not detected')
        self.root.ids.frame_counter.text = f'Faces: {len(faces)}'
        self.counter += 1
        Clock.schedule_once(self.get_frame, 0.25)
```

I can verify that the program can detect faces, because the label shows how many faces are currently detected and I can verify it in the terminal, because the print statements are showing up.

Comment: This code is the 'Solution 2' from https://stackoverflow.com/q/67061962#67061962
It only displays directly the camera image from kivy.uix.camera Camera class and export frames 4 times / sec. That's why you can't draw anything on it.
To use cv2.rectangle() try the 'Solution 1'.

Comment: @NorbertTiborcz I see, I guess I'll just stick with the second solution, because the first solution doesn't work. The app just crashes when opening it on my Android device. Anyways, do you know which part of the code displays the camera in the interface? It wasn't explained by the original author of the 'Solution 2' code in the link.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with the second solution, the only way to draw rectangle around the face is to draw on canvas.

main.py:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
from kivy.clock import Clock


Builder.load_file('layout.kv')


class AndroidCamera(Camera):
    resolution = (640, 480)
    cam_ratio = resolution[0] / resolution[1]


class MyLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass


class CamApp(App):
    FPS = 10
    SCALE = 0.2

    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()

    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.get_frame, 3)

    def get_frame(self, dt):
        cam = self.root.ids.a_cam
        image_object = cam.export_as_image(scale=self.SCALE)
        w, h = image_object.size
        self.frame = np.frombuffer(image_object._texture.pixels, 'uint8').reshape(h, w, 4)
        self.face_detection()
        Clock.schedule_once(self.get_frame, 1 / self.FPS)

    def face_detection(self):
        face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY)
        self.root.ids.lbl.text = f'{gray.shape}'
        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 2)
        if len(faces):
            face = faces[np.argmax(faces[:, 3])] // self.SCALE
            face[1] = self.root.ids.a_cam.height - face[1]
            face[3] = face[3] * -1
            self.root.ids.a_cam.face = face
        else:
            self.root.ids.a_cam.face = [0, 0, 0, 0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CamApp().run()
```

layout.kv:

```
<AndroidCamera>
    index: 0
    allow_stretch: True
    play: True
    face: [0,0,0,0]

    canvas.before:
        PushMatrix
        Rotate:
            angle: -90
            origin: self.center
        Scale:
            x: self.cam_ratio
            y: self.cam_ratio
            origin: self.center
    canvas.after:
        PopMatrix
        Color:
            rgba: 0,1,0,1
        Line:
            width: 2
            points: self.face[0], self.face[1], sum(self.face[::2]), self.face[1]
        Line:
            width: 2
            points: sum(self.face[::2]), self.face[1], sum(self.face[::2]), sum(self.face[1::2])
        Line:
            width: 2
            points: sum(self.face[::2]), sum(self.face[1::2]), self.face[0], sum(self.face[1::2])
        Line:
            width: 2
            points: self.face[0], sum(self.face[1::2]), self.face[0], self.face[1]


<MyLayout>
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size: root.width, root.height

    RelativeLayout:
        size_hint_y: 0.8
        AndroidCamera:
            id: a_cam

    Label:
        id: lbl
        size_hint_y: 0.2
        font_size: sp(32)
```