# How can I display the camera feed using the Kivy Grid Layout?

Tags: python, kivy

I am making an application which will scan an Aruco Marker that corresponds to the user's current location. It then asks for a destination and will display the shortest path to the destination from the current location. I am using Kivy for this as I would like to export it for android later on.

I'm using the Grid Layout and was wondering how I can display the camera feed on my GUI.

This is what I've done so far:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyGridLayout(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGridLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(Button(text="Localise"))
        self.add_widget(Button(text ="Info"))



class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGridLayout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Preferably, I would also like the camera feed to be above the localise and info buttons and span both columns.

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest adding a [Camera widget](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.uix.camera.html) to your `GridLayout`.

Comment: Here is a good starting point to work with camera on android and kivy: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67061962#67061962